# How to copy xmlnodeList into xmlNode and xmlelement

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Help me in writing out code:
1. I have a xml file, I want to read and filter out nodes in a xmlnodeList based on type of nodes(Done).
2. Now, I have to create a Node(say Board) just before the root node and under Board node I am creating xmlElement say Board0, Board1.. with some attributes(Done).
3. Now in Board0, I want to copy my xmlnodeList(Have to write code).

Suppose, my xml file looks like below:

```
Switchboard Version="1.4">
  <Project Port="7353" WDRemotePort="11160" WatchDogSourceAddress="256" IOProtocolVersion="V3" />
  <Controls CountControls="220">
    <IOControl Type="AnalogInput"  </IOControl>
    <IOControl Type="DigitalInput" </IOControl>
    <IOControl Type="DigitalInput" </IOControl>
    <IOControl Type="DigitalInput" </IOControl>
  </Controls>
</Switchboard>
```

Now, I want same file should look like below:

```
<Switchboard Version="1.4">
  <Project Port="7353" WDRemotePort="11160" WatchDogSourceAddress="256" IOProtocolVersion="V3" />
  <Controls CountControls="4">
    <IOControl Type="AnalogInput"  </IOControl>
    <IOControl Type="DigitalInput" </IOControl>
    <IOControl Type="DigitalInput" </IOControl>
    <IOControl Type="DigitalInput" </IOControl>
  </Controls>
  <Boards CountBoards="3">
  <Board0 Name="Alm_HP_RE" BoardWidth="1800" BoardHeigth="1800" Image="" ImageLayout="None">
    <IOControl Type="DigitalInput" </IOControl>
    <IOControl Type="DigitalInput" </IOControl>
    <IOControl Type="DigitalInput" </IOControl>
  </Board0>
  <Board1 Name="Alm_HP_RE" BoardWidth="1800" BoardHeigth="1800" Image="" ImageLayout="None">
  <IOControl Type="AnalogInput"  </IOControl>
  </Board1>
  <Board2 Name="Alm_HP_RE" BoardWidth="1800" BoardHeigth="1800" Image="" ImageLayout="None">
  </Board2>
  </Boards>
</Switchboard>
```

Code I have written :

```
{
    XmlDocument hardwareDoc = new XmlDocument();
    hardwareDoc.Load(f.FullName);
    XmlNode root = hardwareDoc.DocumentElement;
    XmlElement board = hardwareDoc.CreateElement("Boards");
    root.InsertBefore(board, root.LastChild);
    //hardwareDoc.Save(f.FullName);
    XmlElement elem = hardwareDoc.CreateElement("Board0");
    root.AppendChild(elem);
    XmlAttribute attr = hardwareDoc.CreateAttribute("Name");
    attr.Value = "DigitalOutput";
    elem.Attributes.Append(attr);
    attr = hardwareDoc.CreateAttribute("BoardWidth");
    attr.Value = "1800";
    elem.Attributes.Append(attr);
    attr = hardwareDoc.CreateAttribute("BoardHeigth");
    attr.Value = "1800";
    elem.Attributes.Append(attr);
    attr = hardwareDoc.CreateAttribute("Image");
    attr.Value = "";
    elem.Attributes.Append(attr);
    attr = hardwareDoc.CreateAttribute("ImageLayout");
    attr.Value = "None";
    elem.Attributes.Append(attr);

    root.InsertBefore(elem, root.LastChild);
    //COPYING _AnalogInputList into element: 


    hardwareDoc.Save(f.FullName);
}

private static void CreateAttribute()
        {
           DirectoryInfo plcDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\100755224\Desktop\TEST");
           FileInfo[] hardwareFiles = plcDirInfo.GetFiles("test_123.xml");

           foreach (FileInfo f in hardwareFiles)
           {
               XmlDocument hardwareDoc = new XmlDocument();
               hardwareDoc.Load(f.FullName);
               XmlNode root = hardwareDoc.DocumentElement;
               XmlNodeList iosNodeList = hardwareDoc.GetElementsByTagName("IOControl");
              break;
           }

               foreach (FileInfo f in hardwareFiles)
               {
                   XmlDocument hardwareDoc = new XmlDocument();
                   hardwareDoc.Load(f.FullName);

                   XmlNode root = hardwareDoc.DocumentElement;
                   XmlNodeList iosNodeList = hardwareDoc.GetElementsByTagName("IOControl") ;

                   foreach (XmlNode x in iosNodeList)
                   {
                       if (x.Attributes["Type"].Value.Contains("DigitalInput"))
                       {
                           if (_AnalogInputList == null)
                           {
                               _AnalogInputList = new List<XmlNode>();
                           }
                           _AnalogInputList.Add(x);
                       }
                   }
                   XmlElement board = hardwareDoc.CreateElement("Boards-Parent");
                   root.InsertAfter(board, root.LastChild);

                   XmlElement elem = hardwareDoc.CreateElement("Board0-Child");
                   board.AppendChild(elem);
                   XmlAttribute attr = hardwareDoc.CreateAttribute("Name");
                   attr.Value = "DigitalOutput";
                   elem.Attributes.Append(attr);

                   attr = hardwareDoc.CreateAttribute("BoardWidth");
                   attr.Value = "1800";
                   elem.Attributes.Append(attr);

                   attr = hardwareDoc.CreateAttribute("BoardHeigth");
                   attr.Value = "1800";
                   elem.Attributes.Append(attr);

                   attr = hardwareDoc.CreateAttribute("Image");
                   attr.Value = "";
                   elem.Attributes.Append(attr);

                   attr = hardwareDoc.CreateAttribute("ImageLayout");
                   attr.Value = "None";
                   elem.Attributes.Append(attr);


                   XmlElement iocontrol = hardwareDoc.CreateElement("IOControl");
                   elem.AppendChild(iocontrol);

                   if (_AnalogInputList != null)
                   {
                       foreach (XmlNode m in _AnalogInputList)
                       {
                           elem.AppendChild(m);
                       }
                   }

                   hardwareDoc.Save(f.FullName);
           }

      } // end of function
```

My function works fine, the only problem is that, it delete the original Node and copy the node into later element. I want to keep node at both the places. 
I searched and found need to clone the Node. 
Which node to clone ? and How ?

Comment: and what's your problem?

Comment: Not able to put my logic for copying list into XmlElement

Comment: foreach (XmlNode m in _AnalogInputList)
               {
                   elem.AppendChild(m);
               }                                                                                                           Getting exception: The node to be inserted is from a different document context. But they are from the same document. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an answer only for your third question ["Now in Board0, I want to copy my xmlnodeList"]

> How to copy the filtered XMlNodeList into Board0?

1.Use XPATH to select required nodes

```
var nodeList = hardwareDoc.SelectNodes("//IOControl[@Type='DigitalInput']");
```

2.Append the selected nodeList to your board0 XmlElement using foreach loop

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
   elem.AppendChild(node);
}
```